# Android 6 не видит external storage

Tags: android, память, доступ, запись

Делаю программу где требуется сохранять/читать файл на внешнюю память. Пока работал на эмуляторе и Android 5 было все отлично. Установил на Android 6 и запись/чтение не работают. Никаких ошибок и падений не происходит. Что примечательно при запуске и обновлении приложения не происходит запроса разрешений, хотя в манифесте они есть.

Мое приложение слабо читабельно, поэтому предлагаю пример на котором ошибка воспроизводится:
[пример приложения](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/138-urok-75-hranenie-dannyh-rabota-s-fajlami.html)

Также добавлю что устройство с Android 6 - Zuk Z1. Но сомневаюсь что дело именно в нем.

Comment: А вы разрешение на доступ к внешней памяти запрашиваете перед перед попыткой записать/прочитать? в андройде 6 и выше их надо запрашивать теперь кодом. Манифеста мало)

Comment: Оу! А в какой части приложения?

Comment: В любой, надо вам читать или писать - проверяете есть и у вас сейчас права, если нет, то запрашиваете и ждете даст ли их вам пользователь, если так и не даст показываете ему грустный смайлик и сообщаете что не можете работать в таких условиях) Подробности [тут](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень помогло [видео](https://youtu.be/icc9LQTC1Yo), так как не мог найти примеров

Вкратце: создаем переменную

```
private final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

создаем перегруженный метод

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode != MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
        return;
    }
    boolean isGranted = true;
    for (int result : grantResults) {
        if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            isGranted = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (isGranted) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "В разрешениях отказано", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

создаем функцию проверки разрешений

```
private boolean checkPermissions() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

функцию установки разрешений

```
private void setPermissions() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

и в коде вызываем проверку

```
    if (checkPermissions()) {
       Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Разрешения уже получены", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        setPermissions();
    }
```

Comment: Можно ли это вынести в отдельный класс и вызывать при необходимости?